# SharePoint - Developing on a standalone machine without sharepoint server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, sharepoint, windows-7, sharepoint-2010

I want to start learning SharePoint and I need my system setup.

I know I need a SharePoint server, whether on a physical server or a virtual machine. I have done this in the past for the company I worked for. But now I want to use my system to develop but the requirements doesn't meet the SharePoint server specification

I have seen this link and several others on serverfault and they always recommend the Virtual Machine approach

- [Where is the Location of Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332906/where-is-the-location-of-microsoft-sharepoint-dll)

I have also obtain a link to Microsoft Hyper-V pre-installed virtual machine but it's too heavy for my machine.

I have read article that says I should download dlls from a SharePoint server and paste in a replica directory structure on my system

- http://www.techerator.com/2011/02/how-to-perform-sharepoint-development-on-a-client-workstation/

I see that a lot of developer are faced with this challenge and I wish to know if there is now a workaround. Also, what are the limitations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do yourself a big favor and upgrade your development box so that it can handle a VM with SharePoint. Hardware is cheap these days, and a SharePoint capable laptop doesn't break the bank.

The amount of time you spend on trying to come up with a working Gaffa tape solution will soon fall apart again when you need to debug something in a real life scenario. That time is then wasted and you wish you had gone for a proper setup instead.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [CloudShare](http://www.cloudshare.com/). It is worth the price. There is a 14 day trial.