# Reference to Microsoft.SharePoint.dll

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a server that Shrepoint installed on it.

I want to test this code:

[SPUtility.GetLocalizedString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.getlocalizedstring%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

When I add reference to Microsoft.SharePoint.dll I can resolve `SPSite` and ... .The problem is When I want to build the project it does not recognize `using Microsoft.SharePoint` any more:

[image]

and I get this error:

> Error 13  The type or namespace name 'SharePoint' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

where is the problem? I add reference to `Microsoft.SharePoint.dll` but in build time it does not works

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332906/where-is-the-location-of-microsoft-sharepoint-dll  tl;dr -- you have to develop on a machine where SP is installed :/

Comment: I developed on machine that SP installed on it

Comment: Oh! Well.. Hrm. I've tried it once before, worked for me.. other than that, sorry I can't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft.SharePoint.dll from  SharePoint 2010 use  Framework 3.5
but 
Microsoft.SharePoint.dll from  SharePoint 2013 use  Framework 4.0

try it.

Answer (score 2):

Change Visual Studio project solution properties platform target to x64 and the target framework to .NET Framework 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this namespace:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities
```

In the link you gave, it says that the method resides in Namespace `Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities` instead of `Microsoft.SharePoint`. This is just a guess maybe work, haven't tested it,